# while executing org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.codehaus.mojo.exec.Modulepath

Tags: java, maven

The following pom.xml execution fails only when adding "-p" to the org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec plugin, when this argument is removed it runs fine but I need the argument, any suggestions?

This is pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <executions>
    <execution><!-- script -->
      <id>creating-war</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <properties>
          <workspace.location>/space/workspaces/workspace/branch/</workspace.location>
          <property.file>/space/properties</property.file>
      <output.dir>${project.build.directory}/ser
        <properties>
          <workspace.location>/space/workspaces/workspace/branch/</workspace.location>
          <property.file>/space/properties</property.file>
          <output.dir>${project.build.directory}/servoy</output.dir>
          <script.location>/opt/developer/exporter</script.location>
          <admin.username>admin</admin.username>
          <admin.password>admin</admin.password>
          <main.app>app_main</main.app>
        </properties>voy</output.dir>
        <script.location>/opt/developer/exporter</script.location>
        <admin.username>admin</admin.username>
        <admin.password>admin</admin.password>
        <main.app>app_main</main.app>
          </properties>
          <executable>./war_export.sh</executable>
          <workingDirectory>${script.location}</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-s</argument>
            <argument>${main.app}</argument>
            <argument>-o</argument>
            <argument>${output.dir}</argument>
            <argument>-data</argument>
            <argument>${workspace.location}</argument>
            <argument>-p</argument>
            <argument>${property.file}</argument>
            <argument>-defaultAdminUser</argument>
            <argument>${admin.username}</argument>
            <argument>-defaultAdminPassword</argument>
            <argument>${admin.password}</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This is the error trace from console after running mvn clean install:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-  plugin:1.6.0:exec (creating-war) on project servoy-export-war: A type incompatibility occurred while executing org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.codehaus.mojo.exec.Modulepath
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.6.0/exec-maven-plugin-1.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.5.6/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-api-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/asurace/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `exec-maven-plugin` bug, reported [here](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/issues/75) and is not resolved yet. Suggested short term workaround is adding `<longModulepath>false</longModulepath>` optional parameter.

Comment: Thank you, adding the   work around <longModulepath>false</longModulepath>  solved the problem,  lets home the plugin gets updated and fixed in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Updating maven to latest version fixed this.